# I am getting this error " ERROR Error Code: 200 Message: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/login"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

This is my Login.component.html pass formdata to OnSubmit method  i want to send formdata from angular front end application and want to login if username and password match to existing registered persons (in mysql)

****This is angular Reactive login form****

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="panel panel-primary pb-3">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Instrutors Login Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-body">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="username">User Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" ng-model="mymdl">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="submit">login</button> <p> <a routerLink="/register">Signup</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

A This is login.component.ts file it get the form values and pass to the service to generate server request

```
//this runs on  "http://localhost:4200/login/login"

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {LoginService} from '../shared/login.service'
import { Login } from '../shared/login';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  information:any;
  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    username: [''],
    password: ['']
  });


  constructor(

              private  api : LoginService,
              private fb : FormBuilder
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit():any{

      this.api.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((data)=>{
        alert("User Registerd"+this.loginForm.value.firstname)
      });
    }
```

This is login.service.ts file  it uses http method to call the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable,throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {retry,catchError} from'rxjs/operators';
import{Login} from './login';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

//httpOptions
httpOptions={ 
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type':'application/json'
  })
}
//httpCrud Operations For RestFull Api
login(logindata:any): Observable <Login> {

  return this.http.post<Login>(this.apiUrl+'/login',JSON.stringify(logindata),this.httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  ) };
```

Node Api files with database connection

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('mysql');
var http = require('http');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');

//starting server
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

//creating database connection
var con = db.createConnection(
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: "root",
        password:"",
        database: "angular"
    }
);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
//body parser for JSON format data
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    if(username&&password){
        con.query('SELECT * FROM register WHERE username= ? AND password=?',[username,password],(error,results,fields)=>{
            if(results.lenghtL>0){
                console.log('user logged in');
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;
                res.redirect('/home');

            }
            else{
                res.send("incorrect data ");
            }
        res.end();
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send("Please Enter Username and password");
        res.end();
    }
});
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("listining on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: The title does not contain a question!

Comment: Quentin sir , Title include error , question is also for solution of that error

Answer (score 0):

Your back-end API is totally wrong. If you want to use session in this is not make seance. If you call this login API form a mobile device ??? then what happens ??? and you are not returning anything from back-end. Just rewrite the API. Why you use `res.end()` it work like `exit`

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
if(username&&password){
    con.query('SELECT * FROM register WHERE username= ? AND password=?',[username,password],(error,results,fields)=>{
            if(results.lenghtL>0){
                res.json({loggedin: true, username: username});
            }
            else{
                res.json({loggedin: false});
            }

        });
    }
    else {
        res.json({loggedin: false});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav Golui please suggest me any book or article

Comment: You are welcome. please check this source code. https://github.com/souravgolui/matDash. This is in MongoDB.

Comment: :-) Thanks for sharing  Sir " Sourav Golui" please suggest me one thing more ,, i am doing my final year project , i learn and used SQL and sql queries most of the time , so there are many articles ,, as in your also with mongodb ? shoud i use mongodb or Mysql?

Comment: " shoud i use mongodb or Mysql? ". its depends on your project. Mysql is a relational database and MongoDB is non relational database. if you use MySQL no matter .

Comment: Thanks Dear Sir "Sourav Golui " With replacing your above mentioned corrected code that error gone but new error shows please help me , look once again "User Registerdundefined"

Comment: in console this error shows "{loggedin: false}
loggedin: false
__proto__: Object",

Comment: Now you can check if `loggedin` is  `false` show some error message and if `true` now it is logged in

Comment: Thanks  Dear Sir " Sourav Golui"

Comment: You are welcome . can you please approve and up vote this answer :)

Comment: Surely Sir i did upvote but unfortunately this option does not allow me to public  my vote because of new in this platform ,

Comment: i use console.log(username) api receives correct data but unfortunately it generates an error , i think this may be SQL query issue or logical issue to matching the values from sql database ? is that please have a look

Answer (score -1):

This issue is not at the node side, it's at the Angular side
While sending the request you should also mention what's the response you are expecting, Since you have not mentioned anything, you are getting this error
Find the below code which resolves you issue

```
login(logindata:any): Observable <Login> {

  return this.http.post<Login>(this.apiUrl+'/login',JSON.stringify(logindata),{ this.httpOptions, responseType: 'text' })
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  ) };
```

Comment: responseType: 'text' sir i did paste this code , "responseType:" generate an error is anything /module file need to import ?

Comment: try using this { headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json' }

Comment: (property) responseType: "arraybuffer"

Comment: Please send me the complete error, so that i can have a look at it. thanks

Comment: ERROR in src/app/shared/login.service.ts(24,81): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ this: any; responseType: "json"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

Comment: httpOptions={ 
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type':'application/json'
  })
}
//httpCrud Operations For RestFull Api
login(logindata:any): Observable <Login> {

  return this.http.post<Login>(this.apiUrl+'/login',JSON.stringify(logindata),{ this.httpOptions, responseType: 'json' })
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  ) };

Comment: no it should be like 

this.http.post<Login>(this.apiUrl+'/login',JSON.stringify(logindata),{ headers: this.httpOptions, responseType: 'text' })

Comment: vs code highlight error on "header:" -> "(property) headers?: HttpHeaders | {
    [header: string]: string | string[];
}"

Comment: While in console this error shows " 

   ERROR in src/app/shared/login.service.ts(22,23): error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
    src/app/shared/login.service.ts(24,73): error TS2322: Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        ."

Comment: Thanks Alot Dear sir , i did change api code with above mentioned code of sir " Sourav Golui "  now new error just alert not shows in console "User Registerdundefined"